# Troubles with activity title language

Tags: android

I have two language in my app. **values/strings.xml** and **values-ru/strings.xml** When I programmatically change language, all strings translating, but activity title is unchanged. I use in all Activities

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String languageToLoad  = prefs.getString("prefLanguage","en");
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

When I select language, activity or application is reloaded.

Comment: this is my problem too... please answer this.

Comment: I got title set from resources within the manifest but still no translation taking place

Answer (score 26):

i used another way it seems stupid but it's work

in each activity try to set the action bar title to your activity title from values file

in my case i was using `sherlockactionbar`

so i added this in `oncreate` of my `productdetails` activity

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_product_details));
```

Comment: If you set the title as Activity's `label` in AndroidManifest.xml you can re-use it this way: `int labelRes = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), 0).labelRes;
   if (labelRes > 0) {
    getActionBar.setTitle(labelRes);
   }`

Answer (score 8):

Adding `setTitle(R.string.activity_title)` in `onCreate()` updates the Activity title as well as the content itself on changes in locale in Runtime.

Following is the simple snippet that updates its content and activity's title to Korea (ko-KR) when the button is clicked:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Activity title will be updated after the locale has changed in Runtime
        setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Resources resources = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
                Configuration conf = resources.getConfiguration();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    conf.setLocale(Locale.KOREA);
                } else {
                    conf.locale = Locale.KOREA;
                }
                resources.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

                // Overwrite the default Locale
                Locale.setDefault(Locale.KOREA);

                // Clear the back stack then restarts the activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally got a solution:

---

Get `resouce Id` of the activity's title from `PackageManger`, and set the `AcionBar`'s title to the resource id, this time because the Locale is already changed android knows which activity title to pick.

```
try{

    ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), 
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    if(actionBar != null)
        actionBar.setTitle(activityInfo.labelRes);

}catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex){

    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
        "Error while getting activity info. " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

}
```

Comment: Seems to. :) I tried it with both locale changes via the sys menu and locale changes via setting the locale in code. I tried on a device running Marshmallow using appcompat and systheme activities.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in following manner and worked for me.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.app_name));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Use this code after changing local configuration.