# How to change action bar language when language is changed in android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, locale, android-sharedpreferences

I created a application which has privilege to change the language. I used a `SharedPreference` to store the changed language. Then I used it for language change.

These are my steps,

```
public class SaveSharedPreference {

    static final String PREF_LANGUAGE="language";

    static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }    

    public static void setLanguage(Context context,String language){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_LANGUAGE,language);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getLaguage(Context context){
        return getSharedPreferences(context).getString(PREF_LANGUAGE,"");
    }

}
```

This **SaveSharedPreference** class help me to store and get the changed language.

Once I changed the language, I use below step to get and put changed language.

```
if (SaveSharedPreference.getLaguage(context).length()!=0) {

        if(SaveSharedPreference.getLaguage(context).toString().equals("si")){
             String languageToLoad = SaveSharedPreference.getLaguage(context); // your language
             Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
             Locale.setDefault(locale);
             Configuration config = new Configuration();
             config.locale = locale;
             getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        } else {
            String languageToLoad = SaveSharedPreference.getLaguage(context).toString(); // your language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
} else {    
    String languageToLoad = "en"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

I put this on **onResume()** method.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
}
```

And these are my string.xml files for languages,

**values\strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="label_dash_board_name">My dashboard</string>
</resources>
```

**si\strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="label_dash_board_name">දත්ත පුවරුව</string>
</resources>
```

I have gained a problem after changed the language. I could change language in `EditTexts`, `TextViews` and `Buttons`. But I couldn't change the language in action bar.

I can see the language changed when I close and launch the application again.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: instead of action bar you can use toolbar which is more flexible to modify

Comment: @AbhishekSingh : I used a `NavigationView` with my activity. So I have to used a action bar.

Comment: lankawe kollek neh :) issue is only with a.bar right ?

Comment: @Charuka : Yes bro. Danatama godak weda app eke iwarai. me awula thamai thiyenne.

Comment: By any chance, do you also have the styles.xml file inside the values-sinhala folder? This could cause problems with the ActionBar becoming NULL. (check you have styles in your sinhala values machan)

Comment: @Barrier Navigationview can also added with tool bar .. if you need code then I can provide you.

Comment: @Charuka : ActionBar is not becoming Null. It replaces with the string value from the `values\strings.xml` whether I have choosed `Sinhala`.

Comment: "I can see the language changed when I close and launch the application again." so when you open it in the second time it works as expected right?

Comment: @Charuka : I haven't any styles.xml file in my values-sinhala folder

Comment: @Charuka : Right dear.

Comment: show how you set title to action bar , that code snippet , i think if you get as expected in the second time it means there is no issue but only the flow matters , first you check shared value before you set text to a.bar right ? check that flow bn

Comment: @Charuka : I found a solution . Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Barrier  okay good luck

Comment: is setTitle worked or not?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh : It worked

Comment: Check this too --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884068/troubles-with-activity-title-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTitle method may work for you---

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// Activity title will be updated after the locale has changed in Runtime
setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```